Rigid geometric transformation of arrows
Suppose you have two arrows t1 and t2 of the same length. What is a geometric transformation that maps t2 to t1?
My code bellow generates random t1 and t2 and then makes transformation on t2 to map it to t1 (red arrow after transformation).
I want the transform preferably in the form of AffineTransform instead of my cumbersome code.
t1 = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {2, 2}];
t2 = (ra1 = RandomReal[{0, 3}, 2]; 
   ra + # & /@ (ra = 
      RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]; (RotationMatrix[ra] . # & /@ t1)));

Graphics[{Arrow@t1, Arrow@t2, Dashed, Red, 
  GeometricTransformation[Arrow[# + (t1[[1]] - t2[[1]]) & /@ t2], 
   RotationTransform[-PlanarAngle[{0, 0} -> {Subtract @@ t1, 
        Subtract @@ (# + (t1[[1]] - t2[[1]]) & /@ t2)}], t1[[1]]]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Medium]




Have you tried FindGeometricTransform?

@lericr Yes, that would be another solution, but I prefer affine transform because I can use also symbolic input, which FindGeometricTransform does not allow.

First, we create 2 arbitrary arrows with the same length:
SeedRandom[1];
t1 = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 2];
t2 = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 2];
t2 = Normalize[t2] Norm[t1];
t = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 2]; t1 = {t1 + t, t};
t = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 2]; t2 = {t2 + t, t};

Now to get the affine transfromation, wee need the rotation matrix and the translation vector. Toward this end, we move the arrows to the origin to get the rotation matrix:
t11 = Subtract @@ t1; t21 = Subtract @@ t2;
rm = RotationMatrix[{t21, t11}];

The translation is then the second point of t1
:
 translate = t1[[2]] ;

Finally the affine transfromation:
affine = AffineTransform[{rm, translate}];


Now we can draw the graphics:
Graphics[{Arrow[t1], Green, Arrow[t2], Dashed, Red, 
  Arrow[affine /@ {t21, {0, 0}}]}, Axes -> True]



Why did you choose affine to act on {t21, {0, 0}} like affine /@ {t21, {0, 0}} and not some other, say affine2, that would act straight on t2 like affine2 /@ t2? Would be that affine2 much more complicated?

Affine transformation acts on points, not on arrows.

...because transformation in my code acts straight on t2 and maybe this is why my transform is cumbersome.

Yes, affine2 /@ t2 would act straight on the points of t2.

The definition of affine2 would be affine2 = AffineTransform[{rm, t1[[1]] - rm . t2[[1]]}]; and used as Arrow[affine2 /@ t2];. So it is indeed more cumbersome than yours affine.
